# PHP get all character of foreach item and put on second page

Tags: php

I have a small invoice web tool. 
So I would like to find out the total amount of all positions of items and if it reached a maximum level it should print the following positions on the second page of the invoice.

I use the sample code to "design" my invoices: 
http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/LFAes/

My idea is: first count all characters of the foreach loop. 
But I don't know how I should continue?
Please give me some hints. Thanks

EDIT: here is my foreach loop code:

```
<?php foreach( $items as $it): ?>
        <tr class="even">
          <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $pos; ?></td>
          <td style="width:47%;"><?php 
          $string = $it->invoice_item_text;
          if (strlen($string) > 350) $string = substr($string,0,350).'...';
                  echo $string; 
                  ?></td>
          <td style="width:15%;">
          <?php if ($it->invoice_item_type == 3) {$date = date('M Y', strtotime($it->invoice_item_date)); } else { $date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($it->invoice_item_date)); } ?>
            <?php echo $date; ?>
          </td>
          <td style="width:20%;"><?php if ($it->invoice_item_time != '0') { if ($it->invoice_item_type == 1 or $it->invoice_item_type == 2) echo gmdate('H:i', $it->invoice_item_time);}; ?></td>
          <td style="width:10%;"><?php echo number_format($it->invoice_item_sum, 2, ',', ' '); ?> €</td>
        </tr>
        <?php $pos++; ?
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show some code you have already?

Comment: In which format you want invoice?

Comment: I use this sample code to design my invoice: http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/LFAes/  In the end its a simple HTML site which I can print

Answer (score 0):

Use php Array as session variable

```
$_SESSION['items'] = $items;
```

if you store value in session you can use this value any page

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote a bit confusing: the position should be available on a printout, not a second web page.

Comment: use session like array <?php foreach( $_SESSION['items'] as $it) ?>